# how to get particular string from mysql results set

Tags: mysql

I have mysql result set as below and want to get string between `<A></A>` and `<B></B>`

Result set from select query :

`<T733 C="-1" S="16" T="3" U="2"><A P="1">100000002</A><B E="1"
P="1">!ZDM0MmFiNjItZTFlMC00ZTJhLTg2Y2ItNDUyZDgyYjdiMjg5</B></T733>`

output expected from above,
`100000002 !ZDM0MmFiNjItZTFlMC00ZTJhLTg2Y2ItNDUyZDgyYjdiMjg5`

Output should return anything between `<A P="1">` and `</A> && <B E="1" P="1"> and </B>`

Comment: Are you sure that that is a "result set"? To me, it looks like a string?

Comment: Looks like valid XML. So use an XML parser. But you will still need to write code.

Comment: yes, this is result set. longtext column. can we do it by mysql?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING(contents,POSITION('"1">' IN contents)+4,9),SUBSTRING(contents,LOCATE('"1">',contents,45)+4,LOCATE('',contents,45) - LOCATE('"1">',contents,45)-4 )
FROM table1;

Contents is my column name.